What statistic best estimates the sample mean in case of missing data in a distribution?
I have samples of particles and am interested in the particle lengths. The problem is that the samples are assessed using image analysis. As the particles overlap, the measurements are incomplete and longer lengths are over-represented relative to shorter ones.
How can I estimate the average particle length in each sample from the biased set of measured lengths?
You can assume:

The measurement of the longest particle is accurate in each sample.
However, the mean measurement or median measurement may not reflect the mean length or median length accurately.
The number of particles in a sample varies between 10 and 50.
Each particle typically overlaps with 1 to 5 others.
The distribution of lengths is unknown but presumably not Gaussian, and likely slightly skewed to large values with few short values.
The distributions for different samples can vary, but have similar shapes.
The accuracy of a statistic can be computed as the expectation of its squared error.

What statistic based on this information would most accurately represent the average length for each sample?

If there is an answer, it would depend on what you mean by "best represents the average".

@PeterFlom Intuitively, if I have N samples, the sum of squared deviations between the true means and my selected statistic for those distributions is minimized, so that the SSE is minimal.

OK. Please edit your question to include that -- not everyone reads comments. (And welcome to CV!)

I have had good success using physical and geometric models for such situations, such as estimating the distribution of spherical boulders based on thin vertical probes through geological formations.  I believe a careful analysis of the particle geometries and how they relate to the image analysis might similarly be the most effective approach here.  I can't offer any specific pointers due to the vague description in this post.

For the obscured particles, do you observe partial data (censored lengths) or you can't even detect them in the data at all (truncation)?

@dimitriy particles may not be visible in the image because they are completely masked by larger particles. Smaller particles may be either  on front of or behind larger ones. Data is missing for those behind and fully masked.

The way I interpret the setting suggests solutions based on robust statistics. When measured by the breakdown point, the empirical mean, sample maximum, and sample minimum are not adversarially robust, as changing only one sample can make them arbitrarily large. In contrast, the median is a robust measure of central tendency, as it requires half the samples to be outliers before the median can be moved outside the range of the non-outliers.
If the underlying distribution is symmetric around the median (e.g., Gaussian), the Hodges–Lehmann estimator is a consistent and median-unbiased estimate of the population median. If the underlying distribution is not symmetric, the Hodges–Lehmann estimator converges to the pseudo-median, which is a valid measure of central tendency and remains "close" to the true median even when the distribution is fairly asymmetric.

I find the language here unusual: "make them as large as desired". Do you mean "make arbitrarily large"? // Thanks, this is a useful way to think about using the median. Note however that part of the problem is missing data, not erroneous data such as outliers. A good example would be something like the spectral distribution of the sun although in my case I don't know the shape of the distribution other than to assume it is unimodal.
